# Many question askers seem to only want the code, not to understand how to solve their problem

Tags: discussion

It's a challenge, in general, to debug someone's code problem remotely, especially when a question is vague or ambiguous. But sometimes I have a pretty good idea where the issue lies, and how to ferret out the problem, so I suggest debugging / problem solving steps. These are typically for questions no one else is touching anyway.

It seems to me that many question askers, (newbies mostly, granted) don't care about software development process; they want an answer that 100% solves their vaguely worded question, and they want it now. I guess what bugs me most is the lack of comprehension, that software development is work, and it takes time and um, effort.

What does everyone do about this? Avoid trying to answer any question unless it's a simple syntax question?

Comment: Maybe I answered my own question..."These are typically for questions no one else is touching anyway. "

Comment: In addition to just leaving them, you can downvote or vote/flag to close with an appropriate close reason (often one of unclear/too broad/"questions seeking debugging help must..." applies).

Comment: Honestly, I worry about retribution if I start being too active on that front. Should I?

Comment: @ValerieAsensio as a user with <3K, you won't appear anywhere in the close history if you flag it for closure.  And even when you get enough rep to actually close questions, most of the users describe do not have enough rep to downvote, so retribution is rare.  And when it happens, the system has mechanisms that detect suspicious voting patterns.

Comment: That is all good to know. Thanks! @psubsee2003

Comment: And if you have 3K +, one down-vote won't hurt you.

Comment: I'm a far from 3k+, so I want to avoid being down voted for the wrong reason.

Comment: @ValerieAsensio: Agree. it was meant as follow up from psubsee's comment: *if* you have 3K.

Comment: [Random example of the day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407656/keep-actionbar-clickable-always). Well, a couple of days old, but this poster Did Everything Wrong.

Comment: Wow. That's quite an example. @Jongware

Comment: I've downvoted a couple of thousand times and (voted to) close a whole lot of questions -- only once or twice have I received a retaliation. Don't let that hold you back from cleaning up some of the daily mess!

Comment: @ValerieAsensio In my experience, revenge votes are much less common than people might think. I frequently comment on questions (and answers) to point out problems. I have cast over 2000 close votes. I don't think I have gotten more than a handful of downvotes that looked like they were in response to something I might have done or said. Of course you shouldn't insult people, but direct and well founded feedback will very rarely give you a bad response.

Comment: As a fairly new user myself, I have gotten the idea (whether correctly or incorrectly) that if I ask questions about the software development process I get downvoted. So all I can do is ask for that line of code. (But I do appreciate people like you who do give advice about the software development process.)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure. I see what you're saying. Makes sense.

Comment: In those cases I'll add a comment instead of posting an answer and vote to close the question. If it's not possible to post an answer that solves the problem but instead a need to teach the OP how to debug then the question is not a good fit for this site in the first place. I'll sometimes post a few follow-up comments if they keep asking about things but if it looks like it's going to go on for a while I just ignore it and move on.

Comment: I avoid simple syntax questions, or else I take the time, with such questions, to provide teaching of principles in a comment or answer, while explicitly _refusing_ to "write your code for you". The OP may not like it, but I'm writing for posterity.

Comment: Your question takes poorly asked questions on Stack Overflow to task in a very articulated way.

Comment: Why, thank you. When I asked, I thought it might just blow in the breeze without response. I'm blown away by the the many thoughtful and well-reasoned replies.

Comment: Shame on me, but I stopped trying to explain how to/suggesting debug for  newbies because meanwhile I'm doing this, someone else's answers and get all the points, so I prefer answer rather than suggest OP to debug. But I try to deep explain my answers as well.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez

Comment: @hjpotter92, I often see this at tutorial sites, "plz email me the code with following modification  ASAP my email is beerindia2009@gmail.com"  Seems like SO has some sort of filter, as I never see these in First Posts or Late Answers.

Comment: @JonasCz: _we_ are the filter.

Comment: I feel an equal problem to be those users who jump on others assuming all they want is a coded answer for them, sometimes questions are made specifically to increase understanding, even in scenarios where code may exist in other questions. This is becoming an equally as frustrating problem as I had my question shot down by someone who assumed I just wanted the answer handed to me.

Answer (score 165):

You shouldn't be writing your answers specifically tailored to the specific scenario asked about in the question or specifically tailored to the specific user asking the question.  Your answer should certainly solve their specific problem, but your answer shouldn't be quite so specific.

Instead, you should write your answers for a different audience.  You should write your answers keeping in mind that hours, days, weeks, months, even years after the original question was asked and the spoon-feed answer was marked as an answer, the question and its answers will still exist.  Importantly, the question and its answers will still very much turn up in Google search results.

The audience you should be writing your answer for is the audience that will have arrived to the page because their specific problem is somewhat related enough to the problem you're answering to the point where this page has turned up in search results.

The better and more all-encompassing your answer is, and the easier your answer is to understand without the specific context of the question's specific problem, the more likely you are to get a good long-term answer.  And if you're playing the reputation game and want to get large amounts of reputation, the best way to do this is by having answers which serve as good long-term answers.  And the more likely the question is to turn up in search results, the better off you are.

You are right--often times new users (particularly those who are also new programmers) just want the "Right here, right now" answer and don't care about an explanation or any warnings or caveats, they just want to be able to turn in their homework assignment.  But these askers also probably aren't even going to upvote, and you're lucky to even get an accept check-mark out of them.

But that doesn't actually mean that they're never asking interesting questions--sometimes they actually are.  Sometimes, they've stumbled into asking an actually good question without realizing (or caring about anything that makes it interesting).

If the question is a legitimately interesting question, post a complete-explanation answer.  Why?  Because legitimately interested Stack Overflow users who know where to find the upvote button will stumble across your answer days, weeks, months, and even years later, and they will reward your good answer with upvotes.  Or in some cases, if the answer is *especially* good, they might even drop a bounty on your answer.

---

Consider [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498158/intercept-obj-c-delegate-messages-within-a-subclass).

This is that user's *only* Stack Overflow post.  All they did is ask this question.  And clearly, all they wanted was a here-and-now answer.  They got it, and marked it as accepted.  You probably don't have the reputation to view this, but the accepted answer actually has three downvotes (one of which is mine).

[image]

Meanwhile, the second answer has to date 49 upvotes.

And perhaps more importantly, look further down.  The third answer, yes, has just 3 upvotes, but I considered the third answer the best option by a long shot, so in addition to giving it an upvote, I rewarded it a +100 bounty (the equivalent of ten upvotes).

It's also worth noting here that this example was originally asked in August 2010.  The accepted answer was posted on the same day.

The answer which has received 49 upvotes was posted in October of 2010 (so a few months later).

The answer which has 3 upvotes and +100 bounty was posted in September of **2013**, three years after the question was originally asked.

And I didn't stumble across any of this until January of this year.  That's over a year since the answer I awarded bounty to, and nearly four and a half years after the original question was asked.  I found the post, upvoted the good answers, downvoted the bad ones (including the accepted one), and awarded a bounty.

Comment: +1... Remember to link this answer in your moderator nomination...  :)

Comment: Although you're right about my not being able to see the downvotes detail I could see that this a brilliant example to address the question. I've never seen a question / answer roll out quite like that. Thank you.

Comment: After your answer here, the linked answer was violently downvoted :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Not as heavily as the good answers were upvoted.

Comment: How about introducing a second blue tickmark that indicates that answer has been loved most by the audience, or by mods/admins? There could be a minimum time gap like 6 months or so kept after which the blue tick becomes applicable.

Answer (score 50):

My thinking is that even if the OP isn't interested in or doesn't appreciate whatever general problem-solving advice you can offer, if you have something useful to contribute, go ahead and say your piece. Someone else with a similar problem might find the question later, and benefit from your insight.

Comment: That has been my hope, that someone may get something from the answer even if the poster's response is crickets.

Comment: +1... don't know how many times I've arrived at an SO post with a gem of an (unaccepted or low-voted) answer at the bottom of the thread that suggested a scenario that exactly fit my use-case.

Answer (score 39):

I feel your pain! Sadly, we get a lot of questions on SO from [cargo cult programmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) who throw together a few slabs of code that they've found online and then they come here, expecting us to connect the pieces together for them.

Granted, *some* of the newbies that do this *are* genuinely interested in learning how to program properly, and will be grateful for explanations, although their current focus is on simply getting their program to function correctly. OTOH, many of them seem impervious to such explanations.

My guess is that such people aren't really interested in programming theory - what little programming knowledge they have has been acquired from a combination of skimming over a tutorial or two (skipping the boring theory stuff), and doing lots of unstructured trial & error. And without the necessary background theory it can be hard for them to understand any but the simplest explanations.

If you spoon-feed such people with complete working code you're rewarding their bad behaviour, and then next time they have a problem they'll just repeat their [help-vampirism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) with another bad question, since they got the desired result last time. So if you feel impelled to answer such questions it's probably best to respond with hints and small code snippets rather than a complete working program.

However, as nhgrif, Jim Lewis, and matt have indicated, answers aren't just for the benefit of the person asking the question. A good Stack Exchange question is one that inspires answers which will help not only the OP but also many future readers. Sure, help the OP to solve their specific problem, but do it in a way that will also help others in a similar situation in the future.

That can be hard to do if the OP's code is riddled with a bunch of only vaguely-related problems, which is one reason why questions that don't focus on a specific problem are generally not well-received on Stack Exchange sites. Also, such multi-part question can attract a bunch of answers that each focus on one particular sub-question, so the resulting answers don't form a coherent body. FWIW, I discussed a related issue in my answer to [How to write a debugging request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291234/4014959).

For more thoughts on this topic, I urge you to read [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand) (written by Stack Exchange co-founder, Jeff Atwood) if you haven't already done so.

In closing, I should mention that the system rewards those of us who answer neglected questions from grateful new users with insufficient rep to vote: you can win the [Unsung Hero](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero) badge.

---

Addendum

I acknowledge that it's hard to learn to think like a programmer. It can be frustrating to have some familiarity with the language syntax and the main tools that the language provides but to not know how to actually apply that knowledge to solve a particular programming problem. Working with examples of good code written by others can be helpful in that regard, but you *do* need to try to understand what the code's actually doing. You need to get experimental, pull the code apart, put it back together again, and change things to see if the modified version does what you think it should. Etc.

However, cargo culters tend to treat the code slabs they find (or are spoon-fed) as mysterious black boxes. If those code slabs are well-written modular code, the cargo cult strategy can work (to an extent), but it doesn't actually increase your programming ability. IME, it's not easy to break long-term cargo culters from that mindset.

Comment: That's true. All the great online tutorials, like Hartl's rail tutorials walk you through a tremendously complex construct and make it feel easy. And it is smooth as silk when the answers are handed to you, but step of the path and it's quicksand without a base You make a great point.

Comment: I can say as a former code teacher that many of my students come here to ask questions once and never come back.  Even more search here for answers and don't otherwise participate in the site in any meaningful way.  I think you gotta make your peace with it...

Comment: @DaveKaye: Anonymously searching for answers is a much more positive behavior than reaching straight for the "Ask Question" button with a localized problem that will never benefit anyone else and complaining when the question is closed as a duplicate of a thoroughly written explanation, pointing to the two-sentence answer promoting bad practices left before closure as evidence that the question was good.  Anonymous read-only viewers who *contribute nothing* are valued members of the community, just like visitors to a public library.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not sure why you feel the need to point that out but there's a huge difference between poorly asking a question of a large and mostly anonymous tech community and writing a book.  To further the anaology you can also contribute in myriad ways to the library without ever writing -- or reading -- any of its books.  Not so with SE.  Some people have lousy questions but some people could have excellent questions but are lousy askers.  We'll never find out if we don't let them try.  And they'll never learn the difference if we don't let them try.

Comment: @DaveKaye: Just saying that "search here for answers and don't otherwise participate" is not a problem that needs to be solved -- being a searchable resource is a primary goal of SO. All too often I hear the attitude that SO has no value to new users if we don't welcome terrible questions. But we should not look at the "Ask Question" button as ever being an entrypoint for new users. Usage must always start with searching and reading.  Some who are well-organized may graduate to asking and answering quickly, others take longer, and some never get there. But asking is an escalation, not a start

Comment: @BenVoigt Not sure we're *too* far apart on that.  But one thing I think this site sometimes forgets (and that other parts of SE are a bit more forgiving about) is that everyone starts out an idiot.

Comment: @DaveKaye: I don't believe that everyone starts out an idiot. Sure, many newcomers are ignorant of the style & culture of SO, but surely it's not _that_ hard to pick up if you have the patience to read the Help pages, and to look around at a reasonable sample of the questions and answers to get an idea of what's considered good & bad here. IMHO, SO isn't a place for actual idiots - they don't have the mental capacity to become competent programers. FWIW, I'm more than willing to cut ignorant newbies a little slack, but I try to guide them into better behaviour with my comments & answers.

Comment: @PM2Ring I was being hyperbolic to make my point.  "Idiot," "beginner," "noob" -- take your pick.  Everyone starts at the beginning.  I would certainly not want to push away young programmers who are asking questions that the more experienced among us might find "stupid" which is something I do think happens more than it should.  Not everyone asking "how do I?" belongs in the cargo cult -- it's hard to learn to think like a programmer!

Comment: @DaveKaye: Yeah, ok. I try to be welcoming to newbies, and I agree that many of them may be intimidated by the reactions that their "dumb" questions can evoke on SO. OTOH, I also sympathize with SO members who have little patience with questions that should be answerable by anyone of average intelligence who's read a standard tutorial on the language, or with questions that could by answered by 5 or 10 minutes using a search engine. FWIW, your comments have prompted me to add a little more to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I try to make sense at least once a day.

Comment: Oh and this, agreed, no place for it on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976509/how-to-make-a-sites-menu-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen

Answer (score 22):

> What does everyone do about this?

I complain bitterly in chat about the decline of our industry then I go to the pub to get drunk.

Comment: I approve of this method.

Comment: That is talking!

Comment: If it weren't for all the wrong reasons I'd give this an upvote!

Answer (score 12):

Okay. I can't choose a "right" answer. It's all good discussion here, and I learned something from each reply. I'll summarize my takeaway:

1. If a question is so broad or vague as to have little potential for any useful information being shared in an answer - downvote and let the process take care of the rest. Do it for the sake of helping Stack Overflow stay tidy and focused. You won't face the threat of downvote retaliation until you are over 3k votes, and then 1 or 2 DVs won't have major impact. In addition, there are algos that track abusive voting patterns.
2. If a question is vague, but interesting ask clarifying questions in the comments section, see if the OP cares enough about solving the problem to supply details. Then proceed to answer, if there's a question to answer. Or answer the question how you think it will best help someone who searches on this type of question.
3. If a question is interesting, answer it. Answer it not for the the OP who may or may not acknowledge the answer, but for those many, like myself who search and find insight in a answer on SO that breaks the logjam.
4. You'll probably learn something new and reinforce your own knowledge by answering someone else's question, by looking at a diff. problem in a new way through someone else's eyes. (I added this one, because I find it to be true.)

The key consideration is the persistence of the answers is a dividend that keeps being paid (forward), not the particular attitude (e.g. cargo cult) nor the objectives of the OP. This should have occurred to me prior to the discussion because I've used SO as a resource for years. I respect greatly the idea behind this insanely valuable tool. Mostly because I was in the SW trenches before SO was a thing, when there was no global mind to tap into so easily.

Thank you, unsung heroes of Stack Overflow. This has been tremendously helpful to me, and no doubt to others who will come along with the same type of question.

Comment: "downvote to close" downvotes and close votes(or flags for <3k) are two different tools and don't always have to be used together. Just because it's downvote worthy doesn't necessarily mean it's close worthy.

Comment: I'll edit that.

Comment: Note that the anti-serial-voting algorithms are a lot less effective if you have one or two questions, since oftentimes revenge voters will target questions, as they don't cost rep to downvote, and the scripts can't detect patterns when they're that short. If you have, say, zero questions and five answers, or 100 answers and four questions, things are a bit safer.

Answer (score 11):

I'm fairly new to this community, but I like the format.

It takes practice and experience doing questions that will matter and be solvable. Also the one asking might be skipping details that should matter, but does not know it be needed. I think this is why we have comments so we can correct the new one (like me) to the proper questions that should be answered.

I'm was surprised I could not answer any question with ease, but looking at the question themselves made me realize it requires more than experience or comprehension. It may also require good communication via comments and confirming if that is really the same problem they had.

Comment: I like to format of the community too, and I'm trying to learn the ropes. The answers here are all very helpful to that end. I've been using the comments more to ask follow up questions. If someone doesn't reply to the question with more info. It seems to be a good sign that they're not there to solve the problem, just to dine and dash.

Answer (score 8):

I know, this answer won't be liked much. I am an egoist. I don't care too much if an answer is valuable for the asking user. Ok, it **is** nicer if it is. And sure, even better if it is valuable for others, too. But the main reason for me dealing with questions here is to learn. I learn best from mistakes. Some mistakes I would never make myself, so it is sometimes a bit hard to recognize their effects. Helping with debug question helps me to train code reviews and problem solutions when I work in a team. Dealing with stuff here forces me a bit to come out of my comfort zone. Learning from other developers mistakes.

So, someone wants to go easy? Is not interested in software development processes? So what? Sooner or later they learn, change their ways or get what they deserve.

Comment: When I research or think about someone else's question, I always learn something. And if someone comes in with a better answer, sometimes I  learn something very interesting. I keep those filed.

Comment: I like this answer because it reserves the least amount of judgement on the asker.  It simply answers the question asked and the community can upvote/downvote to their hearts desire.  I agree with using question answering as a personal learning tool and I think answering obscure and "noob" questions are a good way to keep yourself grounded to what some junior devs start off like.

Comment: If you want to train for code reviews, you can always become a code reviewer on [codereview.se] - that site isn't about fixing code issues though, it's about taking working code and making it better, more maintainable, secure, performant, etc. Try it, it's a pleasantly different experience ;)

Answer (score 7):

I see exactly what you mean. It's a little bit face/palm to admit that I began as one of those users. It probably took me a year to start asking even remotely decent questions.

Even though my rep here is measly, I've come an incredibly long way since I joined. I was a *¿do-you-haz-teh-code?* noob, and I didn't even start looking at the console until maybe a year and a half ago. Now, with HTML, CSS & JS under my belt, I'm eyeing up C++ and Java. I amaze myself with how easily I can read both, and I have absolutely no doubt that it's heavily due to the time I've spent here reading everybody else's wonderful explanations.

What I hope I'm trying to say is, **sometimes these help-leeches and code pests do get better**. Imo, dealing with 100+ help-leeches is worth helping one decent developer.

Sorry to poke at SE here, but I think the problem *still* lies with the induction process, and the help center. It could be much better, maybe as a mandatory much-more-interactive tour for all new users, that truly exposes the culture and expectations here.

Comment: This made me laugh "¿do-you-haz-teh-code?"

Comment: I suppose everyone has their own threshold for how many "help-leeches" it's worth helping for each decent developer they reach. For much of the target audience of this site, the threshold is probably fairly low, on the order of one or less, and may even decrease over time. I think this is why you will see a lot of discussion on meta about how to keep "help-leeches" etc. out of the site, rather than how to help them understand how to use it, and also why I'm guessing not so many people will be sympathetic to the point you're making here. Still, a good point to bring up.

Comment: @DavidZ thanks for sharing your thoughts. There's just one distinction I'd like to make. I said *dealing with* 100+ help-leeches, not exactly *helping* them. The better the automated mechanisms are suited to this purpose, the faster they can be dealt with. I'm not even saying treat anybody differently, because as long as they're treated respectfully, a decent developer won't mind reading the docs or complying with requests, and they'll come back with better questions eventually. I guess my entire point is just an attempt at a silver lining.

Answer (score 5):

As a new member of the Stack Overflow community and a relatively new programmer that has learned much of my programming ability through on the job training I have come to realize what a helpful place this community is and how well it serves its purpose.

I've found myself in my first couple of days of coming on the community that if I needed help with a problem, I could post and most of the time get an answer that corrected the error in my code and this was great! However, the more time I spend programming and learning new concepts I find myself going back and having to do research on a problem that I've had help solving on here and that isn't how it should be.

So taking a step back and realizing that this community is for the greater good of a vast number of users; I am able to better structure myself, my questions, and my ability as a programmer and for that I give kudos to this great community.

With that, I look forward to growing, and developing with everyone on the community.

Comment: "I find myself going back and having to do research on a problem that I've had help solving on here and that isn't how it should be" -- This is why we tell people to read existing answers, the "I could post and most of the time get an answer that corrected the error in my code" is not nearly as helpful to you as searching for and finding some old question that has been answered with a complete explanation, even though it doesn't have *your code*.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. I think that with new users (including myself) it's easy to get caught up in the thing I'm working on right now. It needs to be about shaping those users to be good programmers, not just Stack Overflow programmers. It took about 5 questions before I finally caught on to that concept! I also find the harder I work for something, the easier I retain it.

Answer (score 5):

As a newbie myself, I'm already feeling this "answer: *working code solution*" culture. I wish people who answer would provide an explanation on how they got there...

Comment: Probably a different discussion point on Meta. I too have noticed a tendancy to 'show off' a bit - giving a solution, but one that's more clever than entirely necessary, which in turn makes it hard to understand. But I think that's tangential to the question at hand.

Comment: @Sobrique: Sometimes people do that when answering what looks like a homework question, as a way of discouraging the OP from passing off the code as their own work, especially when posting a fully-working program. Hopefully, the teacher will recognize that the clever algorithm or advanced syntax is beyond the current skill set of the OP. Think of it as form of watermarking.

Comment: I can understand that, but I don't think it's actually beneficial - after all, surely the _point_ is in helping the supplicant understand, and the actual code outcome is rather secondary? Obfuscation is damaging to that goal in my opinion.

Comment: One time I posted an answer to a question with fixed code, explanation of concept and what the OP did wrong, and link to more info. Two minutes later, someone posts an answer of just the fixed code. Which one is considered better?

Comment: @XamuelSchulman I would consider your answer better, in my opinion. Of course, it always depends on the context.

Answer (score 4):

I think what everyone does about this is answer it when they can if they find it interesting or "worthy". Users who are here to answer questions *want* to answer questions, there is joy in helping others. I read a quote once in one of the SE blogs which stated "never underestimate the value of joy" (I think it was Joel but haven't been able to find it).

The main metric to answering questions is time. If it takes very little time to observe the highlighted behavior, then it will more than likely take very little time to give a correction. This is true of both simple and complex issues, it just depends on how well the behavior is highlighted.

If a question asker has highlighted a behavior in such a way that it has taken every step to reduce the time wasted by reviewing the situation, then there is a very good chance that question will not only be well received but also be given a specific solution.

For me personally, I will answer a question which has a clear solution that is well scoped and does not take long to identify. Sometimes the solution is very complex, and others not so much, but overall it should not take very long to identify.

The implication to answering using these metrics, is that questions which do not follow the pattern of reducing the amount of time it takes to highlight the issue are approached with skepticism. If there is the potential of an issue which was hard to identify the OP can be given some benefit of the doubt. However, as it becomes more and more evident that the OP has not taken steps to reduce the amount of time it takes to help them - or even any steps at all and are just asking for a solution without highlighting anything - then it becomes more and more likely that the question will not be well received. Which is to say it may be actioned by the community in order to show it lacks redeeming qualities by using the available tools; downvoting, closing, and rarely flagging.

Comment: ".. answer when they can .." Actually, it's more when I feel like it. No pressure here.

Comment: @Jongware - Yes, why else be browsing questions if not to answer? :) Choosing which one to answer, or watching the newest feed for a tag, is where the choosy part comes in. I suppose the word "when they can" may have not have properly conveyed my intent with that sentence. What I intended to convey was that if a user finds a question which they can answer, they tend to answer it if they find it worthy. The definition of "can answer" and "worthy" tend to differ from user to user, but in general users looking to answer tend to like answering questions which they consider to be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Loving this discussion. I'd like to share an angle which was what brought me to this community (and apologies, this is getting long) : Social problems needing code solutions, but which don't have veteran coders with high-paying salaries working on them.
I work in the social/sustainability/non-profit sector in a third world country and am bringing IT solutions where there isn't the funding available to pay for a full-time top-notch programmer (ie, I am not one.) This community's impact on enabling good things, with far-reaching consequences, to happen cannot be expressed in monetary terms or individual-learning terms, and I'm extremely grateful for all that I've learned here.

For some, there may be no difference in the same technology being used to manage a private company's internal finances or being used to open up government budget data and making it available to the public (Giving just two examples off the top of my head). I totally respect that, a neutral position is most welcome. But there is more money and R&D being pumped into the former than the latter, there is a status quo bias that prevents good technology solutions being applied to the problems that need them (most simply by what kind of money one can afford to pay). Our socio-economic order isn't a perfect one, the demand-supply mechanisms of our planet are not perfect. No point in running away from the reality of our world while claiming neutrality. To achieve neutrality, one needs to do make some effort, one cannot gain true neutrality by simply doing nothing.

Besides, it's at these "wild frontiers" where amazing challenges and amazing solutions come up. And situations like this pertain directly to the 
"there is joy in helping others" quote. One cannot completely cut away the real world application of the posted question, or blanket-label everyone who's not a full-time dedicated software professional as "cargo cult programmers", etc. The programming profession, by its very nature, is serving the needs of various other sectors and cannot be taken as an isolated thing.

I also stumbled at first posts, was overly expecting direct answers, but am learning now and can actually do the kind of coding that I once believed I could never do. In this process, yes, the working-solution examples have helped as much as proper structural guidance. Even if I'm in India and that example shows provinces of Italy. Why? Because people who are not full-time coders but need to use code in their work, can learn a lot faster from working examples. They might be experts compared to you in, say, identifying plant species, or understanding government welfare programs, or teaching in a classroom. Their requirement might be to learn one component of a technology and not that entire technology. We cannot brand them as illiterate. We cannot demand that they abandon everything that they do and become full-time programmers, or that this community is an exclusive club where "muggles" aren't allowed. The pedagogy of learn-from-example does exist, it fulfills real needs of a large demographic, it has proven to work for them where more mainstream pedagogies have failed, and deserves its place under the sun.

Had there been more draconian policies in place in this network, I wouldn't have gained so much, and several of these problems wouldn't have seen any solutions. There is of course the spam, "answer-this-by-midnight" questions which don't even have a real-world application, much of which comes from the victims of our antiquated education systems that keep bombarding them with yesteryear's questions which already got solved and ought to be in a knowledge base in their university's server or students forum. That's annoying. May I propose guidelines / mechanisms that moderators can use to differentiate between these two kinds of questions, which may be the same technically but whose real-world connections are vastly different?

Answer (score -12):

It's a lot easier to understand code than words. It would be nice to have both, but a piece of code that you can plug in, use, and maybe eventually go back and figure out intuitively on your own time is far better than an answer that doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: What your kind doesn't get is that you _need_ to understand what you're doing. You don't have to understand the "computer science" part of it, but you _do_ need to know how to do more than copy and paste. Otherwise, your mind will become full of garbage. In "understanding" through trial and error, you will get a mind full of false paths which don't really relate to each other, and which cannot be used by you in a general way in the future. Every problem will become a special case.

Comment: I hope to be proven wrong about this. Maybe I'm just being "the old guy". But I fully expect to have to fire a large number of such self-untaught programmers in the future, leaving us with a generation-wide gap in competent software developers.

Comment: John, you don't know me. You don't know my education, employment, or problem solving style. It appears you need to learn to leave your frustration with your employees at work. I'm just trying to answer a questions honestly: I happen to appreciate answers with code because, if you understand it, code contains all the information you need. If it doesn't then you ask for clarification.

Comment: I may be overgeneralizing. But code does _not_ have everything you need. That's one of the serious mistakes being made by many newer developers recently. Code doesn't tell you _why_ it is structured the way it is.

Comment: @user1958756: Only perfect code has all the information you need. No one writes perfect code. And code that is not perfect is usually harder to identify as such than prose.