# How can I go back in time to be the first to ask/answer the trivial questions that today rank highest and become a S.O. Rockstar today?

Tags: feature-request

Since trivial and common questions rank the highest in votes, being first to ask or answer them will be a big bonus.

So in the name of fairness, how can I go back in time and answer all those trivial questions for all the stuff that I know to get the share of votes  that I deserve?

Comment: lol, if you find out how, keep it to yourself:)

Comment: Darn, I was hoping humor was the solution :(

Comment: well, this is a tad ranty

Comment: Hmm, this joke doesn't appreciate the time paradox.  The usual fate of SO users that answer trivial questions is that they quit, bored out of their skull.  You can't go back in time after you quit.

Comment: Apparently this can still happen today. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350504/circular-percent-progress-bar) is way too broad and as such no one answered it. Then a week or so after it was asked, the asker placed a bounty and it started getting many upvotes and answers.

Comment: Look at the profiles of "SO Rockstars" (let's say, top 100 users) and show me one whose main source of rep income was answering trivial questions. I'll wait.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually not necessary to go back in time.

- Sometimes [new languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift?sort=votes&pageSize=50) and [other new languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) come about.
- Sometimes, [entirely new technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) emerge.

And there are other things that can happen that can spark a massive interest in a particular sort of question or tag.  You just have to jump on the boat early.  It's not too late to get in on a simple question with a simple answer that will be used as a resource for years to come when we're talking about emerging technologies.

Also, importantly, sometimes some of the most simple questions can result in a decent number of upvotes for a well-written answer.

[This question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449256/clipstobounds-how-does-it-work/20449468#20449468) is quite simple, nothing complicated about it.  But its one of the top results for a handful of Google searches, and I'll regularly get an odd +10 rep from it here and there.  [Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205550/2792531) of essentially the same principle.

Importantly, don't expect a thousand upvotes the same day you post an answer (there's a daily rep-cap anyway).  Highly upvoted posts play the long game.

For most askers on Stack Overflow, they're largely concerned simply with their own personal needs, and that makes it easy to fall into the trap of simply answering for the sake of their own personal needs.  An answer like that is a surefire way of earning the green checkmark, but what do you want, a green checkmark, or lots of upvotes?  As [I advised in this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291531/many-question-askers-seem-to-only-want-the-code-not-to-understand-how-to-solve/291533#291533), you should keep in mind when writing any answer that the question and your answer may be showing up in Stack Overflow and Google search results for *years* to come.  So while your answers should address the question at hand and solve the asker's problem, if you truly want to write a good answer, be sure that you've included enough description and detail about the problem and its solutions so that it is useful to droves of programmers for years to come.

The key to earning reputation on Stack Overflow is making an investment in the future.  Write answers that will earn you the long-term votes.  Don't settle for writing answers that do the bare minimum to earn the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, all of the low-hanging fruit is gone.  But that's not a bad thing.  It gives you a chance to rise above those really easy questions and provide answers to the rather difficult questions* that others are asking today.

Although to be blunt, the questions don't even have to be that difficult - they just have to have a coherent answer.

If you want to get more votes for the content that you post, then make them as detailed and as useful as you possibly can.  Sure, you can simply solve the OP's problem and get votes like *that*, but the ultimate goal should be to make the content you have as useful and as broadly applicable as possible.

<sup><sup>*: If you can find them.  It's tough to find "difficult" questions nowadays.</sup></sup>

Comment: The questions don't have to be difficult.

Comment: Not really, no.  In fact, I think the top five answers I have were on questions that weren't entirely difficult.  They were just...nuanced.

Comment: My highest voted answers (and admittedly, my highest voted is only +30) are on ones that show up highly in pretty simple Google search results.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's "gone".  The low-hanging fruit regenerates almost constantly, although the community has become very efficient about flagging the duplicates.

Comment: That's kind of what I mean by "gone" - a question that's really basic has already been posted and anything discussing that topic is usually closed as duplicates of it.