# What should be done about users who want too much detail?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a couple of people who are not satisfied with a (correct) answer: they want more detail, and if that is given, even more detail.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578003/how-can-i-convert-between-currencies-in-objective-c-using-either-the-cocoa-or-c/31579188#31579188), for example was last night, but it was not the first. The first time it happened, I got the feeling that I was being played: the asker was seeing how much he could get out of me until I gave up responding. And even after the series of responses, my question was not marked as accepted.

I like helping beginners, but what would be the best way to flag a line of responses as being inappropriate? Is there a way for me to close a question with the warning that SOME effort is required of the person asking the question?

Comment: @MartinJames: thanks. DCV? New acronym for me.

Comment: Down and Close Vote.

Comment: Vampires gonna suck:(  The moment you suspect that you are being drained, DCV immediate.   They're selfish, arrogant, sociopaths  who only care about conning you into providing the best homework answer they can extract.  Sadly, rep DOES matter in these cases - beware 'Member for 2 days', they only want you for your O-neg.

Comment: happened sometimes to me also, just forgot and move forward to see another question

Comment: the best and only real tip you can have here is "try to make them aware of what they're doing. but if they push back again... run"

Comment: You're gonna want to avoid telling someone to accept your answer but otherwise the above advice is correct. You might find this Meta thread interesting as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: If they keep wanting more than the answer you provide, you could provide link(s) to the official API or tutorial (in the answer or comments). I usually try to include a small snippet so there is no confusion in understanding what I mean and just in case a link dies.

Comment: Also, don't forget that fire, decapitation and a wooden stake to the heart can kill.  Despite the popular myths, garlic and sunlight have no effect, though anchovies on pizza can repel them.

Comment: see also: [Link for poor or ever-growing questions to better explain why people stop answering](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253762/839601)

Answer (score 7):

The comments from the OP appear (as [Martin James opined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300066/what-should-be-done-about-users-who-want-too-much-detail#comment224991_300066)) to be symptomatic of ["help vampirism"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). It's not so much "further detail" that such users want; it's for you to provide them with ready working code to copy-paste.  Such requests for you to "send teh codez" should be ignored. Flagging them as "not constructive" would be reasonable.

The Meta question [Many question askers seem to only want the code, not to understand how to solve their problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291531/many-question-askers-seem-to-only-want-the-code-not-to-understand-how-to-solve) should be a good read for you.

> Is there a way for me to close a question with the warning that SOME effort is required of the person asking the question?

I suppose you could vote to close as "too broad" if you really don't feel like you can cover everything the OP wants, but there's a more important consideration.

Your answer is excellent, and solves the problem for any (competent) future reader who is stuck with the same issue. That's [a large part of the goal here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

As I write this, you've gotten four upvotes. The accept is always nice to have, but you've got the approval of your peers (as well as more rep than the checkmark would have given you).

(Also, in general, [avoid prodding askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297597/603977) to accept your answer. It's okay for completely new users, but the wording you used here could be construed as being a little aggressive. At best I'd say this kind of comment is just a waste of words.)

I submit that you've done all you can and should here. Luck of the draw presented you with a bad asker; the next one will hopefully be better. If this bothers you enough, you may also have to do a quality judgement on the question before deciding to answer. As I said above, though, keep the future in mind.

Comment: Thanks - I deleted my aggressive comment and put a more constructive one in its place.