# Should one answer terribly poor questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've been reading Stack Overflow questions and answers for a long time now, probably 5 years now, always my first try on Google, and I have always loved the quality of both the questions and the answers.

Although I have never asked many questions on Stack Overflow because either I find a good solution somewhere or I try hard to solve the issue myself because of being ashamed to ask someone else.

But yesterday I have started my journey on answering questions on Stack Overflow and for my first tries I started with the tag of the language I really know deeply. While watching the new questions coming up, I was surprised by the terrible amount of poor questions, either lacking any effort to solve the issue or being something you'd know if you've read a introduction, tutorial or book about the language, or at least know the very basics of programming and have common logic. Sometimes the OP of those questions do not even correctly pick the best answer!

Currently I cannot downvote, but if I could, I'd very angrily happy (!) downvote those very specific questions. My current approach is to comment on the question (if it can be, amazingly, answered in a single line), because I don't feel very ethical or happy about getting reputation on answering those questions that completely lacks effort. Although I've seen people answering those and getting 6 upvotes in one hour (though the OP is downvoted or 0ed) and I confess it bothered me a bit.

So my question is, should I effectively encourage those questions by answering them? What could I do about them to help the community have less of those?

Comment: If only more people had the same mindset as you :(

Comment: If they are very low quality, or lack research, or lack an example, you can **flag** them. These users that you mention, with their 6 upvotes, are usually repwhores - people trying to gain reputation easily. You do well by not being them. :-) Welcome abroad!

Comment: If there's anybody qualified to answer this question best, it is probably you.  Twice a year, SO is descended upon by students in their end-of-semester term, early November and late April.  Like you.  Q+A is generally quite poor during that period, lasts about 8 weeks.  Turn-out is particularly heavy this semester, they also posts a lot of answers.  Almost looks like they are trying to pad the resume with some SO rep, voting is also very screwy, but that's just a guess. Please give us some insight in how your fellow students like to use SO.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, I don't know, I'm not an programming academic (yet), I just finished high-school last year, eh.

Comment: @Loko +1 I despise any notion of "rep whoring", it's insulting. We are here to answer questions because we enjoy answering questions. Nobody should be inhibited in doing that because somebody else is dictating that *thou shalt not answer this.*

Comment: @deceze its not black & white. The intention should be to create a repository of good questions + answers, so if you focus only on the answers you're still part of the problem. SO also needs people to trigger people to improve their questions - which is a quest without reward of internet points.

Comment: @Gimby I maintain that you should not harass answerers solely based on the fact that they're answering. Downvote their answer *if it's bad*, don't downvote it because it exists. You're not going to educate the masses of bad question posters by punishing answerers. You can still close the question independently of it having been answered. All reputation gains will be reversed eventually if you do. And maybe, just maybe, someone is being helped by that answer, or maybe your own judgement for the quality of this question was misplaced.

Comment: @deceze: "all reputation gains will be reversed eventually": Really? Seems like if either the question or any answer has a positive score, it needs a bunch of 10Ks taking umbrage, in addition to closure (not as dupe) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006

Comment: @Deduplicator Then just maybe the question and/or answer wasn't so terrible after all. I simply take issue with dictating from some high horse who is a "rep whore" and who isn't based on rather vaguely defined terms.

Comment: @deceze: Maybe. Maybe it was just the upvote and/or accept from OP making the post ineligible for roomba. Too many shades of grey, and some of them are icky.

Comment: Sometimes a question that seems easy for you is hard for a beginner. I sense a bit of arrogance in the post.

Comment: I generally ignore poorly written questions. Some are really annoying, like the people posting no code at all and thinking we will just do their job and program their whole application.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to answer bad questions, but if an answer got 6 upvotes it was probably a good answer, most answers to debug-this-code for me questions and the like get an accept mark and one upvote at most.

Comment: @EddyJawed *Easy* questions are not, I think, what the OP is talking about.  They're talking about *bad* questions.  If you've been around awhile I'm sure you've seen plenty of "gimme teh codez now!" type questions .... these are the issue.

Comment: @samgak: You might want to go through the [reversal badges on main](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95). That might change your viewpoint, or at least make you wary... for full effect, wait until you have 10K.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **the premise is flawed** there is no such thing as a *terrible* question.

Comment: __The focus should always be on helping people.__

Comment: Since when does flooding the site with terribly poor questions/answers help people? You help one person with their one problem, and make it harder for hundreds (thousands?) of others to find the help they need.

Comment: If you answer a bad question and I see it, I will downvote your answer, no matter how good it is.  There are probably many others who feel the same.  Don't encourage them by answering.

Comment: @JK.: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98197/should-users-be-penalized-for-answering-bad-questions It's the question that's the problem, not the answer.

Comment: *"So my question is, should I effectively encourage those questions by answering them?"* and *"My current approach is to comment on the question (if it can be, amazingly, answered in a single line)..."* Well, the OP doesn't care whether they get an answer in the answer box or a comment; by doing that, you're still providing an answer. You're just providing one they can't accept, which is bad for SO. Instead, either don't answer it **at all** or answer it with an answer. If the rep bothers you, make it a CW answer.

Comment: the sad thing is that this is even and question and that people are arguing about it ...

Comment: Vote based on content.

Comment: @JK - Also, I am curious how many times you have seen this as you have only posted 5 answers in the past 11 months. Strange that you barely contribute lately and yet threaten other users if they dare answer a question you disagree with.

Comment: I'm no vet on SO, but I see no problem in simple questions and simple answers. If someone has a clear problem and needs a clear answer they can't figure out, I see no reason to think low of it just because it's a simple 1-2 line answer or a complex one. For example, in the python section, `regex` is a powerful (built-in) package for string manipulation, yet many new programmers don't know about it, heck, _I_ didn't know about it until I started browsing SO. In short, I see nothing wrong with simple question, simple answer.

Comment: @Matthew - all the simple questions are dupes, after all these years there are no new unique simple questions, barring a new language coming out really popular: `simple question == unresearched question == dupe`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I wouldn't agree that _all_ simple questions are dupes or unresearched. Many? yes. The majority? Eh, probably. But I'd disagree with all. I browsed through my recent answers, found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006176/confused-about-max-built-in-function/30006210#30006210). Very simple, a mix-up between strings and ints/floats. Something you and I would know, but I figured it out when I asked my dad why files would organize `file1, file 10, file11, file2, file3` etc. If I hadn't, what would I have looked up? I wouldn't know how to, a newcomer would be stuck...

Comment: Please, at the very least, downvote bad questions. Everyone needs to stop being afraid to close and downvote horrible questions. Almost all the bad questions are so specific and poorly written they will NEVER help someone else or even show up in a search, so you're literally doing someone else's paid work

Comment: i would agree, just don't think its fair to think that _all_ simple questions are automatically bad. But like I said, I'm no vet here, but that's my 2 cents for what its worth

Comment: Is this Meta question really not itself a duplicate? It seems to me like this is asking The Core Fundamental Question about what questions are acceptable on the site, and that this question is asked constantly by newcomers who don't understand the model.

Comment: Please don't kill me for this comment, but at one side there comments, advising to downvote bad questions while downvoting is discouraged as it reduces reputation (yes  indeed, there are people who are that picky on their reputation), wouldn't it be a good idea to stop reducing reputation while downvoting?

Comment: @Dominique Some folks do agree that the reputation penalty should go. You can find this in the answers to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting

Answer (score 232, accepted):

There are two broad categories of "bad" questions:

1. debug-my-wall-of-code-for-me questions
2. simple issues with the basics of some technology

**We do not want number 1.** Period. They're of no use to anyone in the future, sometimes not even to the OP right now. It's a complete waste of resources for everyone to spend any time answering a question which will apply to nobody else in the future because the question is both too vaguely worded and the core issue too specific to a code sample too long. Downvote, delete, move on.

Number 2 is trickier. We do expect a certain minimum familiarity with the topic at hand, so super basic questions should be answered by a tutorial, book or manual. *However*, I maintain the stance that as long as the question is clearly worded and well focused, even basic issues are worth answering. Everyone started out learning at zero at some point, and everyone had a time when they "didn't get" even basic issues. That means there will almost certainly be a future audience for even the most basic questions. Having one canonical answer for this one canonical issue is a win-win for everyone overall.

The only thing we do *not* want is to answer such questions again and again. That's what closing-as-duplicate is for, so that should be your first instinct when encountering something which seems so basic that there should already exist an answer for it.

Comment: I think that most low quality questions, are either duplicates(in a way), bad formatted questions, have a very easy solution or just completely off topic(like asking to do peoples homework with minimal effort of trying anything). In case number of 1 and 4, you dont answer them but I think number 2 and 3 should still be answered.

Comment: Indeed. Duplicates are duplicates, off topic is off topic. Bad formatting *should* be improved, but I'd say the necessary improvements must be within reasonable limits; if it's too much to ask then deleting the question is a better use of resources. There are no "easy issues" because everything is easy if know how to do it and everything is hard if you don't; those are exactly the questions we are here to answer.

Comment: With easy issues, I mean like 'just 1 minute of looking for the solution gives you the answer' questions. Might be known as minimal effort to look for the solution. These questions are mostly downvoted because the downvoters know what to look for but the OP doesn't.

Comment: Well, exactly my point. I know what you mean. I'm just clarifying that "easy" is extremely relative. What takes me 30 seconds to type out on my phone in bed before breakfast could easily take somebody else a week of failed research, simply because they do not have the same *experience* as I do. Does that mean the issue is "easy"? For me yes, for the other person no. "Difficulty" is no real criterion for evaluating a question.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. I still stand by my point that a lot of users on SO still downvote if it's this case. I dont because I disagree with the downvotes completely.

Comment: Yes, true. Sometimes it's sad, really. I'm very ready to downvote if the issue has been answered a million times *on SO* and a duplicate is trivial to come by by searching for the exact phrasing of the error message or such, because this truly betrays a complete lack of research. However, if the issue is merely *easy for somebody trained in the arts* but has no existing solution posted, it's potentially a fine question.

Comment: @deceze Also what I would add to point 2 is, that we can neither learn nor read for people. I sometimes post a comment with a link where they just have to read like 2-5 minutes to get to their answer, but some people are just too lazy and just want their copy&paste code and then they are out of here. And against these users you can't do much, because there will always be one user which will post a copy&paste answer, which then encourage the asker  in his behaviour.

Comment: @Rizier Sure. This kind of goes back to having one canonical answer for one canonical (basic) question. Being *canonical* sort of means to be *general*. If the answer or question is too specific to some individual user's code, it's not canonical anymore and probably shouldn't exist.

Comment: @deceze yeah there is where I struggle: If I should answer such a basic question for the future and edit the question, so that you can find it easily in the future OR if it is too basic and I should give them some links to read some basic stuff and close it.

Comment: @Rizier Yes, that can be tough. It depends on the question for me. If the question is already very well suited to be canonical or can easily be edited to be so, then go for it. But if it's too far off, closing is a better use of resources. In other cases I get so annoyed with the lack of canonical candidates that I create them myself (I'm sure you've seen the PHP array sorting reference).

Comment: @deceze Yep I use a few of your questions :) (variable scope, sorting reference)

Comment: I'll happily answer basic questions, if honestly asked. I'm more wary about 'task request' questions though, as I don't like the idea of doing someone's work for them.

Comment: I disagree with 1. Sure, not every 'help me debug' is useful for others in the future, but some mistakes happen again and again.  Sometimes such a question on SO did help me.. even though my code looked totally different. If the question is understandable, if the shown code and the error messages are fairly complete, I think questions like that can be of value for SO.

Comment: @Greenflow Yes, not *all* debug questions are bad. But they should contain at least some relevant keywords which already point in the right direction. Otherwise the question will never be found by anyone searching for relevant terms.

Comment: @Greenflow It depends on whether the question is a nice clean post with MCVE, or it is a huge monstrosity interspersed with walls of code. There is nothing wrong with concise examples of some misbehaving code, but jumble of nested loops over few methods with a lot of shared state usually warrants to be closed as "why isn't this code working".

Comment: @Eugene Podskal, yes... but this is the problem with general categorizations like in deceze's answer: It **always** depends. And hey, with the right comments even the worst questions can get some value: As example how NOT to ask. ;-)  ;-) smiley = don't take this statement too series.

Comment: A lot of the time the basics are really helpful for people who prefer the format of stackoverflow to the standard documentation - for example - almost all MySQL questions are easier to read here and the answers are easier to parse.

Comment: @Greenflow Note that I'm specifically talking about two categories of ***bad*** questions. I never stated that all debug questions are bad. Only bad debug-my-codez questions are bad. There are whole other categories of questions that this answer does not pertain to.

Comment: @deceze, sloppy me. You are right.

Comment: I agree that debug-my-wall-of-code questions are _usually bad_, but they are sometimes redeemable with a little coaxing, especially if you can convince the OP to create an MCVE. FWIW, I discussed why debugging requests are generally unwelcome on SO in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291485/4014959), so I won't bother repeating myself here.

Comment: @PM2 Sure, if a bad question can be improved to be a less-bad or even good question, that's great. However definitive I may sound in my statements, I'm only painting with a very broad brush in order to get somewhere. It's impossible to encapsulate every possible nuance and situation in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Understood, and I agree that it's usually not worth the effort trying to fix such questions.

Comment: There is no quality criteria anymore [*With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed **answers to every question** about programming.*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), you are wasting your time being offended by an outdated criteria for behavior, search the `Tour` page for the word *quality*,  why would a new user think that *quality* was  a concern, it clearly states **answers to every question** and does not mention *quality* even once! And anyone that mentions *quality* is now just characterized as *mean* and/or *rude* when they try to correct no matter what.

Comment: I think you forgot a category: "3- Here is a (partial/ incorrect/ nonsensical) description of my assignment, how do I do this, I have done none of it yet."

Comment: @Dave That's not even a question; this answer pertains to *"bad" questions*, not to assignments. ;o)

Comment: @Jarrod Uhm... The second point explicitly highlights "Don't ask about..."...!?

Comment: Don't related questions pop up as you're asking one?

Comment: Everyone started learning at zero, but _they don't have to learn it here_! They need a book, tutorial or course, they do _not_ need to learn one question at a time.

Comment: @JohnSaunders There will always be questions, even while you're reading a book. And where do you draw the line? You can learn virtually everything from some book somewhere. Do we require questions to not be answerable by a book before we accept them? That's a tough criterion to enforce.

Comment: Well, no, not that tough. For C# questions, for instance, it's reasonable to require that the OK understand simple flow control (but not recursion or exceptions), variables, data types, simple methods and parameters. If you don't understand a `foreach` loop yet, then you don't need to be asking about it here.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What about asking virtually the same thing as a "foreach question" in the Haskell tag? I may be a professional programmer fluent in a dozen C-like languages, but I'm having a hell of a time bending my brain around the idea of doing something simple akin to a loop in a pure functional approach. Everything is easy once you know it, but sometimes you need to ask questions in order to get to know it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Put another way: are *you* going to create an objective, comprehensive list defining minimum required difficulty for each and all possible technologies? Really?

Comment: @deceze: of course I'm not going to create such a list. I've already got all the list I need, right in my head. When it's clear _to me_ that someone needs _teaching_ as opposed to _answering_, I will behave accordingly. As I have been doing.

Comment: And maybe you don't get "looping" in  a functional language because you need to be _taught_, by a _teacher_, and not by a _tutorial_.  Long story very short, but I failed Calculus 1001 three times before I took it as an independent study. I needed an instructor to watch me to see what concept it was that I was missing (it wasn't obvious). Turns out I didn't get the concept of "infinity". I thought it was just "a really large number". Books didn't do the job for me - I needed a human to see what the problem was.

Comment: @John Sure, books don't always cut it, we're in agreement there. Does that mean the only alternative always is another human, never a question on SO? I disagree. When I got into Python, I *understood* Python; it's not that different from other C-like languages after all. However, I would have the stupidest little basic questions; things like proper dictionary access or proper string interpolation and such. A book or manual has the answers *somewhere*, but SO has *awesome*, to the point answers for all these things. It was a lot easier finding those than finding a human or chapter in a book.

Comment: @deceze: those aren't the kind of questions I'm talking about. I'm talking about _basics_ of the language. I'm not even sure your Haskell question would be basic enough. That one seems like there should be one or two canonical "how do you loop in Haskell" questions here. But we don't need any "what is a variable" questions for C#, nor "what is a `for`-loop). See some of the discussion at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291866/youre-unclear-on-what-youre-asking.

Comment: @John So there *is* a cut-off point somewhere where things are too basic. Sure. However, I maintain that's impossible to define clearly, and I think we agree on that. Hence for me the criterion is: *is the question straight forward and can it be answered in a paragraph or two without repeating a tutorial?* Even "What is a variable?" can potentially be a worthwhile question in this category, if it's clearly targeted towards cementing one's knowledge, rather than *"idk lol plz write tutorial 4 me kthxby"*. Objective evaluation on a case-by-base basis is simply what I'm advocating.

Comment: Your insistence on objective criteria is ill-considered. We don't have the time for that, and I, personally, don't have the inclination. While I don't object to the fact that many developers are now learning in a manner different from the way I learned, I _do_ object to the fact that some of them are not learning effectively by copy-paste-ask-on-stackoverflow. I do _not_ want these people programming my life support equipment! I don't mind taking the risk that I may be wrong about them if there's the chance we can somehow get them _taught_.

Comment: While I don't know how to _teach_ them yet, I do know that "giving them a fish" won't do the job. They need to be "taught how to fish", and [so] is not the place to do that.

Comment: @John I have the same reservations regarding copy-paste-ask dilettantes that you do, certainly. I'm saying that not every "simple" question is automatically in this category. Copy-paste-dilettantes are mostly self-selecting in that their questions are also off-topic by one or more of the established close reasons. I'm advocating for the professional (as in "good") programmer who simply has simple questions about an unfamiliar technology very different from the ones they're fluent in. Those questions tend to be high quality and answerable, albeit "not very difficult".

Comment: @John My bottom line is: "difficulty" is not a criterion, *quality* is.

Comment: I'm really not talking about "easy" questions. I'm talking about the cases where the OP clearly does not understand basics. Sticking to C# and VB.NET, can we agree that if you don't have the equivalent of the first few weeks of "C# 101" or "VB.NET 101", then you really need to get those before asking questions?

Comment: @John Sure, it's tough to impossible to *start your programming career* on SO. But again: if the question itself *is answerable* and straight forward enough and potentially of use to future visitors, I don't see any issue with answering it. The real problem is that most people who are at this novice stage rarely know enough to post questions with a high enough quality to qualify here. So again, they are already ruling themselves out with the established close reasons. They typically do belong into the "bad bad" questions category. YMMV in MS-centric tags, I don't know.

Answer (score 38):

I always comment on posts that attempts to answer very low quality questions, asking the posters to improve his question to meet Stack Overflow standards. I do down vote such questions and explain my down vote and I do vote to delete if I see that OP is not going to improve their post.

If people will get answers for questions that don't demonstrate minimal efforts, many others will be encouraged to do so. This could have very bad impact on both Stack Overflow and the poster himself.
By providing a ready answer for low quality question, OP can easily copy-paste the code and use it without even trying to understand why it works. He might be thinking that he's getting help, but he's **not**!

So IMO, we *shouldn't* encourage such questions. However, if the question demonstrates efforts and OP know what they're asking, I'll be happy to help when I can.

On the other hand, even if the question is about the basic of the basics of some technology, if it's clear, well asked and demonstrates minimal efforts and understanding, it can be answered (it's very hard to have a general rule for such questions, it really depends on the question).

---

I just want to clarify that I **do** vote to close and downvote terribly poor questions. But I **do** comment because I always do when I downvote a post, it helps everyone, specially OP, so they can do better in their future posts.

Comment: ^ **YES, yes yes!**

Comment: I like snarky comments. Ok, does not make me popular, I know... but hey... there has to be at least a little bit fun and reward for suckered in reading bad questions. Example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149126/how-to-install-python-libsvm-on-raspbian

Comment: "No research effort" used to be a close-reason, but it is not anymore. This tells me that the policy makers of SO want me to answer that question. Downvote too, perhaps. But not allowing to answer a question that also cannot be closed doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GolezTrol: "No research effort" was **never** a close-reason, only a downvote reason. You are thinking of "lacks minimal understanding", which meant an answer wouldn't benefit the poster any, because he could not understand it, but was removed due to being abused as such.

Comment: @Greenflow: when pressed enough, [I'm with you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155430/getting-utf-8-19-code-of-emoticons-entered-by-user#comment48432488_30155430) -- but *do* note that many times the sharpest of witticisms are lost on the dumber section of the audience here ... (Also, I try to keep my acrid tongue in cheek 'cause I have received an Officially Warned once already – still, at least that means my facetiousness did not go unnoticed.)

Comment: @Jongware, more then once a really bad question was deleted after one of my comments...I see this as a success. Down voting? Does it really matter for a rep 1 account?

Comment: @GolezTrol Exactly. Questions that shouldn't be answered, should be closed (some of them can be deleted as well).

Comment: So... bring back the "This question doesn't show reseach effort" close reason?

Comment: @GolezTrol It'll bring joy to my life again.

Comment: It's a hard line to define exactly what is a bad question, truly bad questions that won't benefit future users should be closed, either as duplicate because they are basic and already have an answer or because they are salvageable. However many other questions can be improved and will benefit future users, just because you or I understand something and think it is basic means that everyone does...SO means to become a repository of good answers to good questions for any question...so serious consider trying to improve the questions that can benefit future users.

Comment: @Greenflow: Yes, though less than for others: It leads to throttling and then a q-ban. Changing account then leads to a limit of 1Q/week. And while circumvention is just about trivial, those who run into it because they don't care most of the time can't be bothered with that either. Which is a clear win for everyone.

Comment: "*I always comment on posts that attempts to answer very low quality questions, asking the posters to delete their answer because we don't want to encourage such questions.*" - and I would flag your comments as "*not constructive*" were I to see them: if you feel you must discourage such questions vote to close, or down-vote, those questions. Obviously, if the answer is bad then down-vote the answer too, but I don't see the benefit of, essentially, shaming someone into deleting their answer because a question didn't meet your standards.

Comment: @davidthomas I **DO** vote to close. I  don't like to down vote without explaining myself. I comment trying helping OP understand what questions should be asked. So I hope you're flag won't be helpful.

Comment: *"I always comment on posts that attempts to answer very low quality questions, asking the posters to delete their answer because we don't want to encourage such questions."* This feels completely pointless to me. People that ask these questions do it because they are aware of StackOverflow's reputation as a place where you can get answers, not because they spend a lot of time reading others' questions and have formed the belief that low quality questions are accepted. It's not a problem you solve by being difficult. The target audience you're trying to change will never see your post anyway.

Comment: Put another way: how exactly does answering low quality questions encourage others to ask low quality questions, as if they are apt to frequently read the site in the first place? Or are you just trying to bully the original asker into changing their behavior before they recidivate?

Comment: @rwollr We are talking on a very, very low quality questions. Answering very low quality questions leads other users to think "Here I can get answer to whatever question I have, even if I don't do research and don't try to understand the problem".

Comment: @MarounMaroun My point is that the people who write very, very low quality questions don't read other questions on the site anyway. If they did, they probably wouldn't be asking low quality questions. I can almost see how someone can make the argument that you shouldn't answer them to avoid them asking bad questions in the future but the logic behind the "preventative" part doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @rwollr someone has to tell them. Otherwise they can't learn from their mistakes as they're skipping the tutorials and the basics of Stack Overflow. By commenting, I'm trying to lead posters to the good way of asking questions here.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I have no problem with telling people who write bad questions that their questions are bad. The thing I take issue with is telling other people to delete their answers as if it makes a difference.

Comment: @rwollr I edited my question.. Didn't mean that OP should delete his post. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 26):

What you need to remember is this - Stack Overflow is intended to become an archive of wisdom of 'coding knowledge'. It does this by taking in good questions and getting good answers.

The individual supplicant getting an answer is merely a beneficial side effect. So any question coming in should be evaluated on the basis:

- Is it likely to be a useful point of reference to anyone else, ever?

if the answer is 'yes', then it's ok, and worth a shot at answering. The level of knowledge and whatnot isn't really much to do with it - we all started as newbies once.

However, if it's a code dump with 'please fix' or a 'task request' - then these aren't likely to be useful to future users. Both are too specific to the asker and you're just contributing another reference example to the pile that didn't get looked at this time.

If it's answerable but lazy, then that's what downvote is for. There are also a couple of specific 'off topic' close reasons too, e.g. code debugging requests. These should be used in that scenario.

Comment: *Stack Overflow is intended to become an archive of wisdom of 'coding knowledge'* - I think this is an oversimplification. There are many questions that describe project specific problems (referencing internal data types or algorithms) that are very interesting to read, to think about and to respond to. The chance that this type of question/answer is useful to a future reader is microscopic (among other reasons because it will not show up in search results since the identifiers are project specific).

Comment: I would rather say that Stack Overflow is a well moderated forum for programmers, and as a side-effect an archive of wisdom of 'coding knowledge' will be built up.

Comment: If it's interesting, then it was useful.

Comment: Heh, that's a very broad and very subjective definition of useful I'm afraid.

Comment: Upvotes and downvotes are by definition subjective. That's no bad thing.

Comment: Well, your whole post hinges on the definition of "useful", (*"Is it likely to be a useful point of reference to anyone else, ever?"*) so you're not really giving any concrete advice what so ever if you say that the definition of "useful" is subjective and up to the reader.

Comment: Yes. But the OP is then saying 'should I try and answer poor questions' which is also subjective. Point is - if the question is poor, but _you think_ the answer might be useful to others, then go for it. It does no harm.

Comment: I can give you a non-subjective definition of a poor question. (Besides, I don't think it's a valid argument for posting an unclear answer to begin with.)

Comment: @aioobe Stackoverflow is [not](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/) a [forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) at all.

Comment: if this really was the case, the word *quality* would be used in the tour and we would still have the *too localized* close reason.

Comment: I don't know the history between 2015 and now, but the word "quality" is currently used in the tour, and "not reproducible or caused by a typo" covers most of the ground that "too localized" seems to have been intended for (it was removed, to my understanding, mainly because it was getting misused to remove things that people simply thought were too trivial or uninteresting - despite that a large number of beginners could reasonably have the same problem and pattern-match to it).

Answer (score 24):

My litmus test for whether or not to answer a question is this:

*Can I possibly answer this question in **any** way that will be helpful to people who stumble across this question?*

This addresses the common bad question cases:

- Debugging questions
- Write my code
- Literally typing the question title into Google reveals the answer

Because the answer to those questions is usually, "No. Not in a million years."

But, if the answer is yes, then I'll go ahead and answer the question. Sometimes I'm not answering the actual question that's being asked, but the question behind the question.

For instance, if someone is having a specific problem but I can tell it's because they don't understand reference types, or loops, or recursion, I will answer their specific question, but also try to explain why they had this problem in the first place. I operate with the assumption that *most* people asking bad questions aren't intentionally asking a bad question - they just don't know how to ask the good question, and they would ask it if they could.

Though... I also try to improve questions if I can - especially if it's obvious that there's a language barrier.

Comment: Does that in any way depend on the question being on-topic?

Comment: @Deduplicator there has been plenty of meta discussion about not punting crap questions over to another site - we just want *good* questions moved to other pages. If they suck then let's close them here. So far my experience with off-topic questions is either they're so terrible that I can't try to answer them, or they're good and get migrated quicker than they can be answered. And if it's that bad, then it's probably not worth improvement.

Comment: Along that line, I think question quality is like... a sort of S-shaped log curve. Maybe just the left half of the bell curve. There's a long tail of really crappy questions that aren't worth the effort to improve. But there's a certain zone where the effort required to move a question from "not very good" to "pretty good" is minimal. Maybe I'd say it's a question of is there a diamond in the rough, or is it just coal dust?

Comment: I disagree wholeheartedly with posting an answer to an extremely low-quality question, even if you *can* post a correct (and useful) answer. It not only helps keep the poor quality question around (the roombas don't automatically delete bad questions if they have upvoted answers), but it encourages the question asker *and others* to continue to post poor quality questions, increasing the amount of noise and clutter. (*I/They got an answer to the question, even though it got closed/downvoted. I'll ask mine; maybe I can get the same results.* ) This is simply counter-productive.

Comment: Honestly I think my criteria work more like the exception rather than the rule. Only very *very* rarely do I find a low qualtiy question that I'd say is worth answering. 99.9% of the low quality questions are not questions that can be answered (well).

Answer (score 15):

My 2 cents:

- **Give me a code that...**
  Never answer, always downvote, always leave a comment: `Welcome to stackoverflow,(for new users) please read [ask].`
- **Debug my project**...
  Never answer, usually downvote with a comment such as `Please read [ask]. Hint: Too much information`
- **RTFM questions**
  Well, these are separated to 2 main branches:

  1. Questions that shows no effort what so ever of reading manuals: usualy downvote with a comment like `Please RTFM`
  2. Questions that shows some effort but lack of understanding: This is probably the only type of poor quality questions I'm happy to answer.
     I try to give my answers at the level that the OP will probably understand, even if there are other, more advanced solutions out there (i.e I will give a foreach answer to something that may be solved by linq).
- **Unclear questions**
  Depending on the severity. if the question is very unclear, vote to close as well as downvote, and add the usual `Welcome to stackoverflow...` comment. If it can be translated to readable English with a little effort (i.e spelling errors etc`) I would prefer to just edit it and provide an answer.

Basically, I try to always comment when I downvote a question or an answer. I believe downvoting without leaving a comment to explain is harmful more then helpful.

Comment: Well, that's a bit too categorical, and thus falls foul of "there's an exception to every rule". Not saying it isn't appropriate for *terribly poor* questions.

Comment: Well, it's not code, it's human behavior. it's more a rule of thumb then a religious low. I promise no one will try to burn you in hell forever if you answer a *debug my project* question every once in a while... :-)

Comment: I can't agree with a recommendation to deliberately use rudeness like RTFM.

Comment: I actually don't really consider that rude... I guess we can disagree on that. Perhaps RTM will be something you agree on?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Generally, dismissive notes that show no more effort than the asker put forth are rude, whether they're LMGTFY or RTM. RTFM simply adds some implicit obscenity to the mix. Either say nothing at all, or tell them where in the manual to look and (possibly) why there.

Comment: Just testing: Please read [ask].

Comment: @nathan: generally, I think the question should almost always show more effort the the answer. The point being asking for help after you've done some effort, at least a good long hard google search. A question like `how do i add x to y` shows no effort at all and deserve no effort being answered. Remember this is my opinion only; you really don't have to agree (at least untill I'll take over the world...)

Answer (score 12):

**No**.

I think that such questions should not be answered, as this encourages people to ask them.

Some examples:

- **Write-my-code for me**,

  All to often, we get questions where the asker wants some code which does X into the box, and expect their code to be written for them, but they have made **no** attempt to write it themselves. And sometimes the code *does* get written for them, and this is **bad** IMO, as it encourages such questions. Do-my-homework-for-me questions are similar, and in my opinion, they should not be answered.
- **Debug code for me**

  These could be easily answered with a debugger or some thinking, but no, people ask them here, and they sometimes *do* get answered. "My code gives null pointer exception, plz help ?" often gets answered, even though OP could easily solve it themselves, it's just quicker to paste the code here and get an answer in seconds.
- **Questions which are just plain clueless**, and could be answered with *just a few minutes of research*. @Greenflow linked [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149126/how-to-install-python-libsvm-on-raspbian) of such a question, The OP could have found the solution with just a little bit of research, but no, it gets asked here.
- **Questions where OP just does not know what he is doing**
  "I found some code on the internetz, it doesn't work, plz help ?" is all too typical. Yes, I might be able to fix his immediate problem, but his code is just *so* wrong and broken, it won't do what they want, ever. Sometimes, you see people using PHP code which is just plain broken and insecure, or having Android code which is so messed up that it's hard to see what the code *is actually supposed to do*. In my opinion, these people need a good beginners book or tutorial, and they also need to *enjoy* what they are doing, oterwise they will never succeed.

  I made the mistake of [answering one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994754/how-to-create-simple-android-webview-progressbar/30014836#30014836), I only knew what the problem was because he posted a screenshot. My solution works, and fixes his problems, but because of his lack of knowlege, there are a hundred other problems, and it never works right. [Similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154411/jsoup-parsing-bolds-only-displays-one/30155030#30155030).

However, some questions which are real questions *should* be answered, where OP has made an effort, and actually wants to understand what we are giving him. But such questions should not be answered again and again, as @Deceze said.

I've answered quite a few such questions <sub>(I'm a repwhore, I admit it!)</sub>, but I'm trying to avoid answering them, and I think they should not be answered if the OP could answer it themselves.

Comment: **Debug code for me** I am not sure about this one. It all depends on the answer. Even thought the concrete problem solution to a "My code gives null pointer exception, plz help ?" won't help anyone else, a proper answer **how** to solve such a problem could. In other words: The way is the goal.

Comment: *"should not be answered, as this encourages people to ask them"* – generally yes, practically I don't know whether it matters. For every user you "educate" to ask good questions there are ten more waiting. The system is taking care of bad askers anyway eventually, all that's needed is voting on the question itself. I'm not sure how much not answering is additionally serving to educate.

Comment: @Greenflow, The problem is that some askers just want code they can paste and run, and they do not want to learn anything. But yes, helping people learn _how_ to solve their problem is good.

Comment: What about [this gem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30138956/2564301)? [At an interview] "they said like not impressed with this code.so please change my code which will satisfied this requirement.That will help in future interviews." Hopefully that's not for a job in an energy plant or hospital in my neighbourhood.

Comment: @JonasCz don't just answer for the questioner... answer for future readers. And I am guilty of many things, but providing paste and run solutions? N...erm... if the bounty is high enough :-D

Comment: *Questions where OP just does not know what he is doing*. this is just a **superset** case of the ones above, none of the above would be classes of questions if the OP knew what they were doing!

Comment: how about this, where does this rate on the **poor** scale? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218948/java-thread-sync-issue

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, IMO, quite poor. "_I want a quick fix_" This is kind of a "gimme teh codez" thing, seemingly no interest in learning.  Also, if adding a print statement causes the code to work properly, it prob. means that he is doing something wrong, and a quick fix wont really help. Also "Code doesn't work" is ..not a very good problem statement. Also, the stack trace is not visible unless you scroll down the code block, but some bad formatting is forgivable. Especially the first version of it is pretty bad IMO. But maybe that's only me, as it has two upvotes (why ?). Anyways, I downvoted.

Answer (score 7):

Some bad questions are not best dealt with by an answer. In this category I would put those containing a simple typo (perhaps even a single keystroke error) and those where the fault is outside the question and the OP comes back with "Solved - forgot to log on" or similar.

The debug-my-code and very basic type of questions I find better answered by a tutorial, as that is what they need. I have started writing much longer tutorial answers, as one would when teaching a beginner. This has the advantage that they are more useful for other readers and add to the quality of the Q&A repository. It also coaches both the OP and other readers into forming better questions and also learning how to avoid asking silly questions in the first place.

The problem is the OP is not grateful for a tutorial and almost never accepts or upvotes. It is the same in face-to-face teaching where "just tell me what to type, not why I type it" is often the attitude us teachers have to overcome.

The problem with the ones that shouldn't be answered, in my view, is the cumbersome closing system. I have identified hundreds of these which can never be answered, but the flags time-out and they can never be closed either! Often these daft questions have been upvoted several times for reasons that appear to make no sense, perhaps by other confused novices, so will almost never get downvoted away either. One gets left with the dilemma of answering a really bad question as an attempt to indicate why it is a really bad question which gives undue attention to it and looks like mindless necroposting.

Comment: Questions like "Solved - forgot to log on" can be closed as *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers**.* (emphasis mine)

Comment: @GolezTrol - No, they can be flagged for closure and then the flag ages away and they stay. As i said I have flagged hundreds of then. They still remain.

Comment: If other people don't agree with the flag, then that's the case.

Comment: 'The problem is the OP is not grateful for a tutorial and almost never accepts or upvotes'
Surely the problem there is that you _expect_ a reward for your effort even though that is not what SO is about.

Comment: @ClaraOnager I guess I worded that poorly. It was not the reward that I saw as the issue really; perhaps "the OP often does not come back and read and learn from the tutorial" is a better representation. **However**, gamification, badges and points is **exactly** what SO is about!

Answer (score 7):

**Should I effectively encourage those questions by answering them?**

Playing devil's advocate, I'd say "**it depends**."

Generally poor questions that show no effort or research, or one of those 'can I haz teh codez' questions, all which have been addressed in the great answers above, should definitely be flagged or at most commented on telling said asker to Google or read a duplicate question.

However, some low quality questions do have value. There has been a lot of times I have searched online for 'How to do  in ?'. Most of the time I find my answer on SO as the first hit, or some obscure blog, or **a duplicate of another question**.

Here are a few reasons why to answer 'poor-quality' questions:
- No quick and easy reference can be found. It's buried in the docs.
- The question with an answer already is not easily found via search.

**No quick and easy reference can be found**

An example (that does not represent the entire issue, of course) is that one time I searched for 'How to run a python3 script' when learning about Python during a course. There were links to official documentation, entire posts explaining what happens when you run a python script, and in other cases when I search for answers online, it's common to find it buried in a lot of documentation. Answers on SO have been great as it provides the format for a quick and easy answer, followed by a more detailed explanation of it all. I feel that in cases like these we should answer the question, and provide a link to the docs, as well as gently nudging the asker to 'RTFM'. Many questions are answered by reading the docs or even the manual, but how many people actually do that when they can type a few words to search for it?

**Question that already has an answer cannot be easily found**

Perhaps the asker has already tried to search for an answer, and couldn't find one because the actual question did not have enough traffic to bump it up the search results, and relies on more specific keywords to get the question that has already been asked. I feel that questions like these should be answered, with a link to the duplicate, so that future site visitors can find what they're looking for quicker. [After all many questions help point to a canonical answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/where-to-post-a-canonical-answer-when-its-not-in-response-to-a-specific-quest), [they definitely serve a purpose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose), especially for people new to a language or programming concept.

Another reason that the asker couldn't find an answer for it could be because they do not know the right keywords to search for the answer, it's hard to search for something when you don't know what you're searching for. They definitely know that something is wrong, and it can be solved, but they don't know what to search to find the answer they're looking for, so they ask a 'bad' question. That way the people more well-informed on SO can point them in the right direction.

To be clear, that does not mean that we should answer all 'bad' questions. I agree that questions that show no research effort, or tell me what's wrong with my code questions should not be answered, hence my approach when seeing bad questions and considering to answer them or not is to **Google said question.**

Can I find it on the first page, is it clear? Is it a complete duplicate, or a similar question? Did I need to add more keywords to get the answer?

If an answer is not found easily, or does not particularly fit the question, I answer the question, with a link to the question previously asked, as well as provide some direction on where to go from there ("read this, look at that, learn up about this"). I also try to add more information that adds value to the question, stuff that is related to the question, hopefully that way the person that asked the bad question leaves SO learning more about what they didn't even know about.

If it's a question that has an answer on Google or it's too short to give a proper answer, I just tell them in the comments and flag them or let the mods close the questions.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, the question can be edited from a terribly poor question to a mediocre question. I am not sure this Utopian world exists, but it is at least good to keep an eye out for it.

There is a set of questions asked, I will start with the one in the title. *Terrible* questions should be closed for an appropriate reason from the community decided set of choices. If the question does not fall into one of those categories, then it should not be closed and as a result *could* be answered.

The situation of *could* be answered is where the nuance enters. At the border of *could* be closed and *should* be closed is downvote and move on - this is a very viable option and definitely will discourage that type of question composition.

Beyond closure and downvoting and moving on, there is only answering if willing. At this point I would say we are probably not on the topic of terrible questions anymore.

What should not be done is to downvote answers based solely on the fact they were posted on terribly poor questions. Vote based on content. If the answer warrants a downvote because of its content, then by all means.

tldr; Downvote terribly poor questions, step 1. Step 2: check for closure. Step 3: move on.

Comment: "closed for an appropriate reason from the community decided set of choices": When do I get to vote for close-reasons then? And anyway, there's "custom" as well...

Comment: @Deduplicator - There is custom, although it is not often used. Sure, if you strongly believe one of the reasons doesn't fit, custom is an option. Often those questions are very low quality or spam though. Aside from that, the close reasons are often discussed on meta. I think there have been 3 or 4 rounds of them that come through in the past 6 years. The community does have a say in these close reasons though, and if you search long and far (MSE) you should be able to find a very long winded debate and history on the topic. Happy reading! :)

Answer (score 4):

> I was surprised by the terrible amount of poor questions, either lacking any effort to solve the issue or being something you'd know if you've read a introduction, tutorial or book about the language, or at least know the very basics of programming and have common logic. Sometimes the OP of those questions do not even correctly pick the best answer!

Problem solving effort is not a requirement for asking a question on Stack Overflow. [Shog9 gave a great answer about this already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/11107541). TL;DR The requirements for effort are: Definition Effort (clearly defining and scoping the question with enough information to support focused answers) and On-Site Research Effort (using the builtin search bar or another search engine) to search for the question if it has already been asked before on-site. Q&A that address basics concepts are not bad for the site (in fact, many of the highest voted (most useful) Q&A here are those addressing basics).

See also [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/997587) and [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/997587).

That already covers the needs details / needs focus / duplicate close reasons. The rest are defined [in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and expanded upon in [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/11107541). Anything that should be closed is discouraged from being answered (as written in [/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the "Answer well-asked questions" section).

If the asker selects a non-ideal answer to accept (by some definition of "ideal"), then too bad (unfortunately, and to the confusion of everyone who doesn't know that the acceptance feature is *not* the almighty indicator of which answer is best). Just let the masses speak with their votes over time.

As far as I know, anything that shouldn't be closed (or red-flagged, such as spam or rude/abusive content) is fair game for answering, regardless of score. I've sometimes observed non-off-topic questions getting downvoted heavily- probably because people think they are "dumb questions" (like the asker of this meta question described what they think a poor question is)- and then went to search for a canonical question to dup-close to, and not found one. Sometimes in those cases I do what I can to clean up the question post (I almost always do, and this is supported by the last paragraph of /help/how-to-answer's "Answer well-asked questions" section) and then write up an answer. There are real reasons why the [lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat) and [illuminator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) badges exist. If it's a case of a close-worthy question with an un-asked gem of a question in it that is difficult to edit into shape (such as asking multiple questions), I just go and write up that Q&A myself (see /help/self-answer).

> Currently I cannot downvote, but if I could, I'd very angrily happy (!) downvote those very specific questions. My current approach is to comment on the question (if it can be, amazingly, answered in a single line), because I don't feel very ethical or happy about getting reputation on answering those questions that completely lacks effort. Although I've seen people answering those and getting 6 upvotes in one hour (though the OP is downvoted or 0ed) and I confess it bothered me a bit.

Spend your votes however you want. Each user with voting privileges is entitled to vote however they want (as long as it's not voting fraud or serial voting). The masses will speak over time what is useful and makes the internet a better place. The curators will- over time- clean up what is off-topic / close-worthy.

Don't answer questions (those that should not be closed) in comments. Comments are not for answering questions (that should not be closed). The answering being dead-simple and obvious to you is not a determiner of whether a question should get an answer post or not. If it can/should be dup-closed, dup-vote/dup-flag. If it's off-topic, close-vote/close-flag. If it should be red-flagged, red-flag.

If the question is on-topic, not a duplicate, not-red-flag-worthy, those 6 upvotes could have gone to you.

Comment: "The answering being dead-simple and obvious to you is not a determiner of whether a question should get an answer post or not." - yes, **but**: if the question **shouldn't** get an answer post, it is still often possible to *say something in the comments that OP will find useful, and maybe even fix the problem*. For example, if the problem is clearly caused by a typo, then pointing out **where the typo is** could be described as "answering the question", but obviously we don't want to have answers that do this. Do we really want to prohibit people from being helpful in the comments, too?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree with you there. The intention for that statement of mine was to be scoped to non-close-worthy and non-red-flag-worthy questions. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Looking at it again: the first fundamental idea in problem-solving is decomposition, and typically we *do* require a problem to be decomposed (which will entail putting in effort) because otherwise it will **lack focus**.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, one shouldn't answer such questions.

**Why?**

- The question is NOT useful for future users as it has poor quality.
- It would waste the answerers’ time.
- It would encourage the asker to ask more of such low quality questions.
- It would waste the time of users who view the page.
- It would decrease the quality of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -9):

**To add to the downvoted answers here:**

**If you can understand what the questioner wants, and want to give him an answer, then go ahead.** It would be great if you could edit his question so those of us not psychic could also understand what's going on.

**If his question is just too basic for you, that's not bad for the site, just move on and let someone else help him.**  This site is about helping people at the level they're at, it's not just for those of us who've been around more than a few decades. I still ask questions on languages I'm unfamiliar with that are newby level, because lets face it, most documentation sucks.

**There is no excuse to downvote a good answer to a terrible question, but people are free to do what they want with their vote.** Personally, I think those who contribute while having to deal with a poor question deserve more than a normal upvote.

Comment: "There is no excuse to downvote a good answer to a terrible question" - on the contrary: there is **no such thing** as a good answer to a terrible question; **any** attempt to post an answer to a terrible question is **inherently bad**, because its **mere existence makes it harder to keep the site clean**.

Answer (score -19):

Answer awful questions because:

1) What's the first thing you do when you lack specific knowledge? Google it and most likely land on a Stack Overflow page, so when you answer the stupid question, it might give an answer to another person with he same lack of specific knowledge.

2) I'm a subject matter in some areas of technology, but lack miserably in the others. Sometimes end-to-end projects make me work with the tools I know nothing about (I just figured out how to drop some installation files in my Java path, pretty late for a grad student to know that), it's encouraging to have a little bit of hand-holding.

As far as those who answer simple questions, sometimes one answers the simplest questions, like this one which is an editorial piece, simply because that might be the extent of their knowledge.

Having said the above, play no role in finishing someone else's homework/work assignment for them.