# What to do with redundant questions

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of questions that are redundant and with no value to the community. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319545/null-point-exception-on-base-adapter#30319576). Person wants to know why he gets `NullPointerException`, where he clearly did not initialize the value. When I try to find a solution to serious problem, I do not want to go through posts like this. OK, it will help the person, but I do not think it would be of great help to anyone, since it is common error. Should these questions be kept? I think they should be removed once person gets answer, since there is no point in keeping it.

Comment: So downvote and comment what's wrong with the question. Do the stackoverflow thing.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with the question. User doesn't understand and gets the answer. But it has no value to the community.

Comment: "But there is nothing wrong with the question" - of course there is! The user asked a SO question instead of doing some basic debugging, or simply reading their own damn code properly (e.g. highlight all occurrences of the variable in their IDE, it should be obvious what happened). This is pretty much the worst thing you can do, only topped by the clueless noobs who don't know what they're doing and just dump their complete homework assignments verbatim onto SO.

Comment: I see your point. You are right.

Comment: if it is a duplicate, and it is, then there is *something wrong with it*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This goes back to [Should one answer terribly poor questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293931/476)

*No,* we do *not* want these questions. As you said, they're of no use to anyone in the future, since they're virtually incomprehensible *as a question*. They're a lazy debugging request, nothing more. We should not even delete the question *after* it has been answered, the question should be removed *immediately*.

The problem is what reason to remove them *for*. For this it's great, and overall a win-win for everyone, to have *one canonical question and answer* which once and for all describes what a `NullPointerException` is and how it can be resolved. While every code individually is unique (and therefore not a great question to have), the root cause of this error is virtually always identical and the answer usually boils down to exactly the same pattern every time. We just want to explain that pattern once and then direct every user with the same problem to that reference.

If such a canonical reference does not yet exist, consider creating one. Either by rewriting and improving an existing question and answer, or by creating a synthetic self-answered one. Then **close** everything that fits that pattern **as duplicate**.

Comment: But doesn't closing as a duplicate leave the useless questions lying around? A slight improvement, but is it any use?

Comment: The question can still be deleted. But it needs to be closed before it can be deleted. When closed as duplicate it'll even point future users who may stumble upon this in the right direction instead of it just being a dead end.

Comment: OK, but if otherwise closed, depending on answers and votes, it could be auto-deleted. Find a duplicate and then some way for manual deleters to locate it, seems more long-winded.